# Как нарисовать что-нибудь поверх картинки с камеры?

Tags: java, android, графика, камера, shape

Получил картинку с камеры как объясняется в [уроке](http://startandroid.ru/ru/uroki/vse-uroki-spiskom/264-urok-132-kamera-vyvod-izobrazhenija-na-ekran-obrabotka-povorota.html)  и хочу нарисовать поверх какой-нибудь стандартный примитив (линию, круг...).

Не порекомендуют ли гуру как это сделать?

Попытка вставить функцию ниже не удалась.

```
@Override
protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
...
   canvas.drawCircle(500, 500, 300, mCirclePaint);
}
```

Comment: скорее всего onDraw вызывается раньше, чем камера нарисует на канвасе, т.е. круг перекрывается. вам нужно словить момент, где камера вам даёт изображение и на этмо изображении нарисовать круг

Comment: Используйте `CameraFragment` с `FrameLayout`

Comment: 2 Sviat Volkov: пардон, неясно выразился. Я даже вставить onDraw не могу, выдает ошибку  error: method does not override or implement a method from a supertype

Comment: при использовании `SurfaceView` отрисовка должна происходить в методах `surfaceCreated()` и `surfaceChanged()`

Comment: @Dmbor оно вам говорит, что надо в вашем onDraw() вызывать super метод

Comment: @Serodv: Скачал пример с GitHub https://github.com/pikanji/CameraPreviewSample, вставил вызов рисовательной функции как Вы сказали 
'    Override
    public void surfaceCreated(SurfaceHolder holder) {
        try {
            mCamera.setPreviewDisplay(mHolder);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            mCamera.release();
            mCamera = null;
        }
        tryDrawing(holder);
    }'
    Кружочек появляется на долю секунды на черном фоне, потом его заменяет картинка с камеры

Comment: Собственно рисовательная функция
'    private void tryDrawing(SurfaceHolder holder) {
        canvas = holder.lockCanvas();
        if (canvas == null) {
            Log.e("sss", "Cannot draw onto the canvas as it's null");
        } else {
            mCirclePaint.setColor(Color.RED);
            mCirclePaint.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);

            canvas.drawCircle(500, 500, 300, mCirclePaint);
            invalidate();
            holder.unlockCanvasAndPost(canvas);
        }
    }
'

Comment: А, извиняюсь, решил - в surfaceCreated вставил setWillNotDraw(false)   и теперь все рисуется в OnDraw

Comment: Вообще, лучше рисовать картинку в отдельной View, которая будет помещена в FrameLayout после SurfaceView.